# configure outgoing header for zimbra

Tags: linux, centos

I'm using a Zimbra Mail server installed on CentOS.

Which file should I configure for outgoing header to insert my company name and address so our sent emails will not be treated as a spam?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it your headers that are causing rejections or lack of SPF records? What is the error or spam message you are getting?

Comment: It's a lack of both headers and SPF but let me do the headers first and here is the orginal message I'm getting from gmail:

Comment: It's a lack of both headers and SPF but let me do the headers first and here is the orginal message I'm getting from gmail:   from mail.aljeel.ly ([41.78.60.35])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id p56si1021107eeh.133.2012.02.02.02.23.36;
        Thu, 02 Feb 2012 02:23:37 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 41.78.60.35 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of a.tulti@aljeel.ly) client-ip=41.78.60.35;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: 41.78.60.35 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of a.tulti@

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a reverse DNS PTR record...

```
[root@xxx ~]# nslookup mail.aljeel.ly
Server:         172.16.24.14
Address:        172.16.24.14#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   mail.aljeel.ly
Address: 41.78.60.35

[root@xxx ~]# nslookup 41.78.60.35
Server:         172.16.24.14
Address:        172.16.24.14#53

** server can't find 35.60.78.41.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN
```

That's going to be the biggest factor in being able to send mail effectively.